# What you think about Digital-Tutors?

Tags: unity, game-design

I want to ask if there is any one try Digital-Tutors site as content

i see it's very good but i want to make sure before i rush into it .

Comment: Judging by the looks of the site, I doubt anybody here is going to try to convince you not to use it. Meanwhile, this isn't really a question and the tags barely apply, so -1, sorry. But good luck learning 3D and modelling! :)

Comment: @Superdoggy Digital tutors teaches much more then 3D and modeling. It offers tutorials from Cad to HTML and 3D to digitally coloring your sketches.

Comment: @MennoGouw Ah, okay, I only got a quick look at the site and from what I could tell it was primarily focused on 3D modelling software and 3D games. :)

Comment: @Superdoggy It actually targets Unity tutorials as well. Your subscription gives you access to pluralsight which has even more programming related material.

While this is off topic - my answer is I love it and it is worth the money.

Answer (score 1):

This is very subjective. Digital Tutors is very good tutorial site offering top quality tutorial. It can teach you how to use a tool and goes on showing how they use it. But in the end it is not the tool that creates the art, it is you using the tool and be creative with it. That is something nobody can teach you.

Digital tutors does have tutors and specialized learning methods other then your average youtube playlist. However I cannot judge the quality of that but I expect it to be good. I come from the time 3Dbuzz was a free source of knowledge. It teached me a lot of things. They had free courses you could enter and learn from others. It definitely helped me understand the tools so I guess Digital Tutors does too.